# Getting a CSRF error when using python requests for scraping App store connect financial Reports

Tags: python, web-scraping, app-store-connect, csrf, csrf-token

I'm trying to test a connection to one app in app store connect using Python's requests library for web scraping the Sales and Trends Reports in app store connect. When I try this simple code for connection I get a csrf error.

This is my code right now:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

username = "my_username"
password = "my_password"
app_id = "my_app_id"

# Define the URL for the login page and the report page
login_url = "https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login"
report_url = f"https://analytics.itunes.apple.com/analytics/api/v1/data/app/{app_id}/metrics/downloads?measure=UNITS&group=DAY&start_date=2023-01-01&end_date=2023-04-27"

# a session object to maintain the login credentials
session = requests.Session()

# Log in to App Store Connect
login_data = {"accountName": username, "password": password}
session.post(login_url, data=login_data)

# Scrape the sales and trends report page
report_page = session.get(report_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(report_page.content, "html.parser")

# Extract the data from the report
report_data = soup.get_text()
print(report_data)
```

The error is:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\04_app_store\main.py", line 41, in <module>
    "csrf": session.cookies["X-CSRF-Token"],
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hamed\PycharmProjects\Python\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 334, in __getitem__
    return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hamed\PycharmProjects\Python\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 413, in _find_no_duplicates
    raise KeyError(f"name={name!r}, domain={domain!r}, path={path!r}")
KeyError: "name='X-CSRF-Token', domain=None, path=None"```

How should I solve this cookie issues?




My final goal is to do a web scraping project on app store connect Sales and Trends Reports with python and for example get monthly revenue from there. But at first step I faced to this CSRF error.
````

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code in my environment and it worked well,
try running `pip show requests` to see what version you are using.
mine is `Version: 2.22.0`

also try setting http version:

```
from http.client import HTTPConnection
HTTPConnection._http_vsn_str = 'HTTP/1.0'
```